# 3D scatterplot using R

Tags: r, plot

Im' trying to replicate the top 3D scatter plot on [this](https://zell.hedbergandson.com/3d-scatter-plot-using-r/) website,

[image]

Unfortunately, this website doesn't contain any code, and doesn't specify clearly which package is used, and a google search yielded no useful results. I would like to replicate this plot with my own data, and get it in a format that's useful in a publication. Any suggestions?

Comment: This https://r-graph-gallery.com/3d_scatter_plot.html or this http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization might help.

Comment: Likely the package `scatterplot3d`

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Thanks! the second link contains all the info that i need!

Comment: @G5W As far as i can see, this package is not able to do what i want it to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the web page you cite is copying from [this website](https://www.andreaperlato.com/graphpost/how-to-create-3d-and-4d-plot/) ...